# Script for metafont to TTF conversion?

Tags: fonts, truetype

In the [metatype FAQ](http://metatype.sourceforge.net/faq.php), there's a section called "I have Metafont sources of some font. How could I convert it to TrueType using Metatype?"  In that, he lays out a dozen steps that really should be scripted.  Does anyone know of such a script?  (I understand the result won't look very good at low font sizes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a [mf2pt1](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mf2pt1) Perl script which will get you half way there...

But it only converts Metafont to PostScript Type 1 font, which you can then convert to .ttf via [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/)